# Developing vector drawing app on iOS

Tags: ios, opengl-es, render, vector-graphics

I'm interesting into your opinion about what's the best (or rule of thumb) approach to developing vector drawing apps on iOS. The app doesn't need to be drawing app, it can be any graph editor such as UML editor or similar... Bottom line is that all these editors are vector drawing apps.

To implement the drawing I find several approaches:

1. OpenGL
2. Quartz (or CoreGraphics)
3. CoreAnimation - Have CALayers in
   scroll view or similar.
4. UICollectionView - seems interesting with
   custom layout because it will only draw what's currently visible on
   screen

Keep in mind that app should perform well while zomming in/out even in case of several hundreds/thousands objects on scene.

Comment: You need to be way more specific about what your theoretical app is actually doing. A simple graph editor presents a very different set of cases than an Illustrator clone. Any of the four choices you mentioned could be optimal (although CoreGraphics drawing is likely the most broadly preferable)

Comment: UML editor and alike is what I have in mind. So graphics editor should support adding symbols and links between them, zooming, panning, undo/redo (altough this is not related to drawing), selecting elements, resizing them, moving them, aligning...